# How to create a script that auto-logins, fills data in a table, and saves it?

Tags: python, html, authentication, python-requests

I have a [login page](https://semantic-ui.com/examples/login.html)<sup>1</sup> that I want to create an auto login into. This is what I have in mind:

1. use `requests.get` to get the content of the login page
2. figure out what is the element that's responsible for the login
3. use `requests.post` with a form with that element and my password
4. somehow click the login button
5. get the next page, and do the same

(1) went OK, but I'm stuck on (2). I tried using F12 and inspecting the web page, even using the specific element inspector, but I don't get what to do from here... [image]

- Is the element through which I should login is available and I'm just missing it or is this something that is hidden?
- Should I be using JS / some other more web-oriented language for this?

My work so far:

```
import requests
print('\n'.join(requests.get('https://semantic-ui.com/examples/login.html').content.decode().splitlines()))
```

This prints the content, and this is the intersting part, I think:

```
      <script>     
  $(document)
    .ready(function() {
      $('.ui.form')
        .form({
          fields: {
            email: {
              identifier  : 'email',
              rules: [
                {
                  type   : 'empty',
                  prompt : 'Please enter your e-mail'
                },    
                {                    
                  type   : 'email',                   
                  prompt : 'Please enter a valid e-mail'
                }             
              ]
            },
            password: {         
              identifier  : 'password',
              rules: [     
                {                         
                  type   : 'empty',  
                  prompt : 'Please enter your password'                  
                },
                {
                  type   : 'length[6]',
                  prompt : 'Your password must be at least 6 characters'
                }                    
              ]                                                           
            }   
          }   
        })                                                        
      ;     
    })
  ;                                       
  </script>
```

though I'm really not sure what to do from here.

<sup>1</sup> This is an example login page, mine is more of an DB login, to which I wanna login, and modify an entry

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up different things

1. If you want to fill form using requests then you will need

   1. Name of  both inputs in your case which is 'email' and 'password'
   2. URL to which you need to submit form which is action attribute of form and if it is not present that means it is present in any script tag or file

After that you need to make post request to that URL with request body containing 'email' and 'password'

2. If you want to chain complex tasks like logging in and then browsing or something involving browser interaction you need to use python's selenium library which is used in browser automation

And that interesting stuff you mentioned are  form validation rules and not the thing you are looking for